# Voice Over is reading ListTile component main section with title and subtitle as a group instead of one element with text

Tags: html, accessibility, screen, voiceover

```html
<div class="listtileGroup" tabindex="0" role="list">

    <div id="listtile-1" class="listtile" tabindex="0" role="listitem">
      <div class="listtile-leading">
      </div>
      <div class="listtile-main">
        <span class="listtile-main-title">Title a</span>
        <span class="listtile-main-subtitle">Subtitle lorem Ipsum is nice</span>
      </div>
      <div class="listtile-trailing">
      </div>
    </div>

<div id="listtile-2" class="listtile" tabindex="0" role="listitem">
      <div class="listtile-leading">
      </div>
      <div class="listtile-main">
        <span class="listtile-main-title">Title b</span>
        <span class="listtile-main-subtitle">Subtitle lorem Ipsum is nice</span>
      </div>
      <div class="listtile-trailing">
      </div>
    </div>

<div id="listtile-3" class="listtile" tabindex="0" role="listitem">
      <div class="listtile-leading">
      </div>
      <div class="listtile-main">
        <span class="listtile-main-title">Title c</span>
        <span class="listtile-main-subtitle">Subtitle lorem Ipsum is nice</span>
      </div>
      <div class="listtile-trailing">
      </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

What I want is that when voice over / screen reader is on, is to be able to navigate between ListTiles, inside the ListTileGroup so the screen reader will read each ListTile title and subtitle without adding the word "group", For example Voice Over reads the first ListTile :  "Title a Subtitle lorem Ipsum is nice, group, 1 of 3".

[image]

And then:

[image]

I tried to remove the roles and change the listtileGroup to ul tag, And listtile's to li tags , but this didn't help.

Comment: I'm more familiar with Voiceover on iOS than I am with a Mac. On iOS, you don't get the "grouping" message. I don't see anything in your snippet that would cause "1 of 3" to be announced. Did you post the code exactly as what you're testing? You usually need a grouping role to get that announced and that might be what's causing your "in a group" message too. Are any of your CSS classes using the `display` property? That can sometimes cause grouping.

Comment: I don't know if it can change anything to the problem, but why do you use tabindex=0 ? It seems totally useless here.

Comment: Sorry, The ListTile is treated as a widget, ListTileGroup is a list of ListTiles. The tabindex was needed on the ListTile because the design wants a focus ring around it when you tab with the keyboard.  Also the LlstTileGroup have a role="list" and the ListTile have a role="listitem". I tried also changing to ul, li without roles but still the screen reader was announcing each ListTile as a group.